# Unable to read data from Amazon Redshift using psycopg2

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

Hi I am trying to read some data from Amazon Redshift table using Python code.

I am using psycopg2 library.

Following is the code I am using:

```
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testdb' port='5439' user='user' host='us-west.redshift.amazonaws.com' password='pass'");
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.set_isolation_level( psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT )
try:
    cursor.execute( 'begin' )
    cur.execute("""SELECT * from employee""")
    cursor.execute( 'commit' )
except:
    print "Unable to select from test database!"
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

But I am unable to read data as it is unable to select from test database.

Please advice.

Comment: So it looks like you're selecting from the employee table in the public schema.  Can you confirm that the "user" userid can select from that table using a query tool like aginity?

Comment: Also, don't do a `BEGIN`, psycopg2 manages that for you. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control

Comment: yes you are right!! So I tried thinking through it and found that the connection string had some access issues and the code works without begin and isolation level too. Thanks mike and fog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put the full name of the redshift instance, which is longer than 'us-west.redshift.amazonaws.com':

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testdb' port='5439' user='user' host='**REDSHIFT_INSTANCE_NAME.redshift.amazonaws.com**' password='pass'");

For example, host would be similar to **'tst.cryibvg33r9d.ap-southeast-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'**